# Silverlight - Check Website

Tags: silverlight

How do I check to see if a website exists at a URL in Silverilght? I basically want to ping a web page. However, the WebClient does not seem to work for me. Is there a way to check HTTP response codes in Silverlight? What does the code look like to ping a web site?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse out the results from http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/.

Comment: Very handy, I didn't know something like this existed. +1

Answer (score 1):

Check out [URL Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008%28VS.95%29.aspx), and here's an example for [Using WebClient and HttpRequest](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest.aspx).